# Total energy for 2 charged particles feeling their potentials: Problem with a factor of 2

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, coulombs-law

Say we have charge $Q_1$ and charge $Q_2$, both exerting a potential $V_1$ and $V_2$ respectively, at a separation $r$.

The interaction energy is $\displaystyle\frac{Q_1 Q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}$.

The energy is also $qV$ in general, shouldn't it be $Q_1 V_2 + Q_2 V_1$ here, ending up with a factor of $2$ to the expression above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy of a system isn't the sum of the individual energies, *ie.* energy is not extensive in general. The energy of the system is the energy required to create this system *out of nothing*. To do it, you can bring the first charge from nowhere to its position: it cost you nothing, since there is no potential at that time in space, except the potential it creates. No, you can bring the second charge, from infinity to its position: it costs you $Q_2 V_1(r) = \frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r}$.

In general, you can show that for any given $Q_1,\dots,Q_n$ charges, then the energy of the system is

$$ E = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} Q_iV_i$$

where $V_i$ is the potential created at the position of $Q_i$ by all the other charges. To do this, consider the result true with $n$ charges, and show that it is still true with $n+1$ charges.

Comment: Great yes sorry forgot how this went